# Can you implement auto fn() -> decltype(exp) as a header/implementation or does it need to be header only?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, decltype

So I have the following example:

header file:

```
class mymapclass
{
    std::multimap<int, int> mymap;

    auto get_mymap_value_range(int key_val) -> decltype(mymap.equal_range(key_val))
    {
        return mymap->equal_range(key_val);
    }
};
```

In cpp file:

```
int main()
{
    mymapclass m;
    auto test = m.get_mymap_value_range(1);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I want to move the implementation of get_mymap_value_range() into the cpp file I get a compiler error (MSVS2012 - not fully c++11, but seems to support this feature): C2228 left of equal_range must have class/struct/union...

If I leave the implementation in the header it seems to work. When I moved the implementation into the cpp file it looked like:

header:

```
auto get_mymap_value_range(int key_val) -> decltype(mymap.equal_range(key_val));
```

cpp:

```
auto mymapclass::get_mymap_value_range(int key_val) -> decltype(mymap.equal_range(key_val))
{
    return mymap->equal_range(key_val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your sample, but `auto` isn't one of them.

You should know about the One Definition Rule. Many C++ entities may be defined only once. For instance, functions and global objects may be defined only once. By putting `mymap` and `get_mymap_value_range` in a header and including that header twice, you violate both rules.

You may need `extern std::multimap<int, int> mymap;` in the header, as that is *not* a definition.

Note that compilers do not have to detect violations of the One Definition Rule. They're getting better at it, but it's quite possible that you end up with a runtime problem. E.g. it would be no surprise when a single variable has two different addresses, each of which holds a different value.

Comment: Are you talking about `#pragma once` or `#ifndef headername ...` ? I forgot to put that in my little example. I can add that - that is not the problem I am facing though I think?

Comment: @code_fodder: That's a header guard. It prevents a single header from being included twice **in the same .cpp**. It won't prevent a header from being included in different .cpp files. So, no, this answer is not about header guards.

Comment: ah crap - you are right - I copied my example from my other PC... but it was implemented as a class and they are class members... I think I need to update my example...